# How to fix compile time error using zxing library in android?

Tags: android, zxing

I am developing an application for a bar code scanner in android. I am using zxing library2.2 and core 2.2. I have developed the application using Google ApI 4.0. I am getting a compile time error in these files:

1. CaptureActivity.Java
2. CaptureHandler.java
3. DecodeHandler.Java
4. EncoderActivity.java
5. HistoryActivity.java

   **`I am getting a compile time error case expression must be constant expresion`**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menu_share:
    intent.setClassName(this, ShareActivity.class.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case R.id.menu_history:
    intent.setClassName(this, HistoryActivity.class.getName());
    startActivityForResult(intent, HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
    break;
  case R.id.menu_settings:
    intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case R.id.menu_help:
    intent.setClassName(this, HelpActivity.class.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
return true;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Will you please mention here all error with class name?

Comment: On SO, whenever you write "compile time error" you should be thinking "I should paste the error".

Comment: The error your compiler is complaining about is that the `case` statements should contains constant expressions. Now when your project get compiled in your `R` class file the IDs are compiled in the form `public static final int some_id = 0xDEADBEEF`. BUT if your project is actually a library project they are compiled instead to: `public static int some_id = 0xDEADBEEF` and that is the reason of the error you get. Now, if your project is not a library project, chances are that you are importing the wrong R class. If it is, you should change the switch statement to an if-else construct.

Answer (score -1):

This is my CaptureActivity.Java class without any error and exception.

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity
    implements surfaceHolder.Callback {
// SCAN
private static final String TAG = CaptureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int HISTORY_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int SETTINGS_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;

private static final long DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 1500L;
private static final long BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS = 1000L;

private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX = "http://www.google";
private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX = "/m/products/scan";
private static final String[] ZXING_URLS = {
        "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan", "zxing://scan/"};
private static final String RETURN_CODE_PLACEHOLDER = "{CODE}";
private static final String RETURN_URL_PARAM = "ret";

private static final Set<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES = EnumSet
        .of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER,
                ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
                ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
                ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);
     // UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
private CameraManager cameraManager;
private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
private Result savedResultToShow;
private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
private TextView statusView;
private View resultView;
private Result lastResult;
private boolean hasSurface;
private boolean copyToClipboard;
private IntentSource source;
private String sourceUrl;
private String returnUrlTemplate;
private Collection<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
private String characterSet;
private String versionName;
private HistoryManager historyManager;
private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
private BeepManager beepManager;

ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
    return viewfinderView;
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

CameraManager getCameraManager() {
    return cameraManager;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    hasSurface = false;
    historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
    historyManager.trimHistory();
    inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);
    beepManager = new BeepManager(this);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // CameraManager must be initialized here, not in onCreate(). This is
    // necessary because we don't
    // want to open the camera driver and measure the screen size if we're
    // going to show the help on
    // first launch. That led to bugs where the scanning rectangle was the
    // wrong size and partially
    // off screen.
    cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());

    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);

    resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
    statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);

    handler = null;
    lastResult = null;

    resetStatusView();

    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
        // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still
        // exists. Therefore
        // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
        initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
        // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the
        // camera.
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    beepManager.updatePrefs();

    inactivityTimer.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    copyToClipboard = prefs.getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.KEY_COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD, true)
            && ((intent == null) || intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    Intents.Scan.SAVE_HISTORY, true));

    source = IntentSource.NONE;
    decodeFormats = null;
    characterSet = null;

    if (intent != null) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        String dataString = intent.getDataString();

        if (Intents.Scan.ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Scan the formats the intent requested, and return the result
            // to the calling activity.
            source = IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(intent);

            if (intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH)
                    && intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT)) {
                int width = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH, 0);
                int height = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT, 0);
                if ((width > 0) && (height > 0)) {
                    cameraManager.setManualFramingRect(width, height);
                }
            }

            String customPromptMessage = intent
                    .getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE);
            if (customPromptMessage != null) {
                statusView.setText(customPromptMessage);
            }

        } else if ((dataString != null)
                && dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX)
                && dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX)) {

            // Scan only products and send the result to mobile Product
            // Search.
            source = IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.PRODUCT_FORMATS;

        } else if (isZXingURL(dataString)) {

            // Scan formats requested in query string (all formats if none
            // specified).
            // If a return URL is specified, send the results there.
            // Otherwise, handle it ourselves.
            source = IntentSource.ZXING_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            Uri inputUri = Uri.parse(sourceUrl);
            returnUrlTemplate = inputUri
                    .getQueryParameter(RETURN_URL_PARAM);
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager
                    .parseDecodeFormats(inputUri);

        }

        characterSet = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.CHARACTER_SET);

    }
}

private static boolean isZXingURL(String dataString) {
    if (dataString == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String url : ZXING_URLS) {
        if (dataString.startsWith(url)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.quitSynchronously();
        handler = null;
    }
    inactivityTimer.onPause();
    cameraManager.closeDriver();
    if (!hasSurface) {
        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    inactivityTimer.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else if (((source == IntentSource.NONE) || (source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK))
                && (lastResult != null)) {
            // restartPreviewAfterDelay(0L);
            Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", text);
            i.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT", type);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    } else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS)
            || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
        // Handle these events so they don't launch the Camera app
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/*
 * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 * super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); menu.add(Menu.NONE, HISTORY_ID,
 * Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_history)
 * .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history); menu.add(Menu.NONE,
 * SETTINGS_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_settings)
 * .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences); return true; }
 * 
 * @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { Intent
 * intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 * intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET); switch
 * (item.getItemId()) { case HISTORY_ID : intent = new
 * Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 * intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
 * intent.setClassName(this, HistoryActivity.class.getName());
 * startActivity(intent); break; case SETTINGS_ID :
 * intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
 * startActivity(intent); break; default : return
 * super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); } return true; }
 */
private void decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,
        com.google.zxing.Result result) {
    // Bitmap isn't used yet -- will be used soon
    if (handler == null) {
        savedResultToShow = result;
    } else {
        if (result != null) {
            savedResultToShow = result;
        }
        if (savedResultToShow != null) {
            Message message = Message.obtain(handler,
                    R.id.decode_succeeded, savedResultToShow);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        savedResultToShow = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (holder == null) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "*** WARNING *** surfaceCreated() gave us a null surface!");
    }
    if (!hasSurface) {
        hasSurface = true;
        initCamera(holder);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}

/**
 * A valid barcode has been found, so give an indication of success and show
 * the results.
 * 
 * @param rawResult
 *            The contents of the barcode.
 * @param barcode
 *            A greyscale bitmap of the camera data which was decoded.
 */
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    inactivityTimer.onActivity();
    lastResult = rawResult;
    ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(
            this, rawResult);
    historyManager.addHistoryItem(rawResult, resultHandler);

    if (barcode == null) {
        // This is from history -- no saved barcode
        handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, null);
    } else {
        beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
        drawResultPoints(barcode, rawResult);
        switch (source) {
            case NATIVE_APP_INTENT :
            case PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK :
                handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
                break;
            case ZXING_LINK :
                if (returnUrlTemplate == null) {
                    handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler,
                            barcode);
                } else {
                    handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler,
                            barcode);
                }
                break;
            case NONE :
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_BULK_MODE,
                        false)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_bulk_mode_scanned,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Wait a moment or else it will scan the same barcode
                    // continuously about 3 times
                    restartPreviewAfterDelay(BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS);
                } else {
                    handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler,
                            barcode);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Superimpose a line for 1D or dots for 2D to highlight the key features of
 * the barcode.
 * 
 * @param barcode
 *            A bitmap of the captured image.
 * @param rawResult
 *            The decoded results which contains the points to draw.
 */
private void drawResultPoints(Bitmap barcode, Result rawResult) {
    ResultPoint[] points = rawResult.getResultPoints();
    if ((points != null) && (points.length > 0)) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(barcode);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.result_image_border));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        Rect border = new Rect(2, 2, barcode.getWidth() - 2, barcode
                .getHeight() - 2);
        canvas.drawRect(border, paint);

        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_points));
        if (points.length == 2) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1]);
        } else if ((points.length == 4)
                && ((rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.UPC_A) || (rawResult
                        .getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.EAN_13))) {
            // Hacky special case -- draw two lines, for the barcode and
            // metadata
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1]);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[2], points[3]);
        } else {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
            for (ResultPoint point : points) {
                canvas.drawPoint(point.getX(), point.getY(), paint);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, ResultPoint a,
        ResultPoint b) {
    canvas.drawLine(a.getX(), a.getY(), b.getX(), b.getY(), paint);
}

String text, type;
// Put up our own UI for how to handle the decoded contents.
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult,
        ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
    statusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
    if (barcode == null) {
        barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.launcher_icon));
    } else {
        barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);
    }

    TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
    formatTextView.setText(rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
    typeTextView.setText(resultHandler.getType().toString());

    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            DateFormat.SHORT);
    String formattedTime = formatter.format(new Date(rawResult
            .getTimestamp()));
    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
    timeTextView.setText(formattedTime);

    TextView metaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view);
    View metaTextViewLabel = findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view_label);
    metaTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Map<ResultMetadataType, Object> metadata = rawResult
            .getResultMetadata();
    if (metadata != null) {
        StringBuilder metadataText = new StringBuilder(20);
        for (Map.Entry<ResultMetadataType, Object> entry : metadata
                .entrySet()) {
            if (DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                metadataText.append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
            }
        }
        // ResultMetadataType
        if (metadataText.length() > 0) {
            metadataText.setLength(metadataText.length() - 1);
            metaTextView.setText(metadataText);
            metaTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
    CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
    contentsTextView.setText(displayContents);

    text = displayContents.toString();
    type = formatTextView.getText().toString();

    // Crudely scale betweeen 22 and 32 -- bigger font for shorter text
    int scaledSize = Math.max(22, 32 - displayContents.length() / 4);
    contentsTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, scaledSize);

    TextView supplementTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_supplement_text_view);
    supplementTextView.setText("");
    supplementTextView.setOnClickListener(null);

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.KEY_SUPPLEMENTAL, true)) {
        SupplementalInfoRetriever.maybeInvokeRetrieval(supplementTextView,
                resultHandler.getResult(), handler, historyManager, this);
    }

    if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(displayContents);
    }

}

// Briefly show the contents of the barcode, then handle the result outside
// Barcode Scanner.
private void handleDecodeExternally(Result rawResult,
        ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
    viewfinderView.drawResultBitmap(barcode);

    // Since this message will only be shown for a second, just tell the
    // user what kind of
    // barcode was found (e.g. contact info) rather than the full contents,
    // which they won't
    // have time to read.
    statusView.setText(getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()));

    if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(resultHandler.getDisplayContents());
    }

    if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {

        // Hand back whatever action they requested - this can be changed to
        // Intents.Scan.ACTION when
        // the deprecated intent is retired.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT, rawResult.toString());
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult
                .getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        byte[] rawBytes = rawResult.getRawBytes();
        if ((rawBytes != null) && (rawBytes.length > 0)) {
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTES, rawBytes);
        }
        Map<ResultMetadataType, ?> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
            Integer orientation = (Integer) metadata
                    .get(ResultMetadataType.ORIENTATION);
            if (orientation != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ORIENTATION,
                        orientation.intValue());
            }
            String ecLevel = (String) metadata
                    .get(ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL);
            if (ecLevel != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
                        ecLevel);
            }
            Iterable<byte[]> byteSegments = (Iterable<byte[]>) metadata
                    .get(ResultMetadataType.BYTE_SEGMENTS);
            if (byteSegments != null) {
                int i = 0;
                for (byte[] byteSegment : byteSegments) {
                    intent.putExtra(
                            Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_PREFIX + i,
                            byteSegment);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        sendReplyMessage(R.id.return_scan_result, intent);

    } else if (source == IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK) {

        // Reformulate the URL which triggered us into a query, so that the
        // request goes to the same
        // TLD as the scan URL.
        int end = sourceUrl.lastIndexOf("/scan");
        String replyURL = sourceUrl.substring(0, end) + "?q="
                + resultHandler.getDisplayContents() + "&source=zxing";
        sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL);

    } else if (source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK) {

        // Replace each occurrence of RETURN_CODE_PLACEHOLDER in the
        // returnUrlTemplate
        // with the scanned code. This allows both queries and REST-style
        // URLs to work.
        if (returnUrlTemplate != null) {
            String codeReplacement = String.valueOf(resultHandler
                    .getDisplayContents());
            try {
                codeReplacement = URLEncoder.encode(codeReplacement,
                        "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // can't happen; UTF-8 is always supported. Continue, I
                // guess, without encoding
            }
            String replyURL = returnUrlTemplate.replace(
                    RETURN_CODE_PLACEHOLDER, codeReplacement);
            sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL);
        }

    }
}

private void sendReplyMessage(int id, Object arg) {
    Message message = Message.obtain(handler, id, arg);
    long resultDurationMS = getIntent().getLongExtra(
            Intents.Scan.RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS,
            DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS);
    if (resultDurationMS > 0L) {
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, resultDurationMS);
    } else {
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}

/**
 * We want the help screen to be shown automatically the first time a new
 * version of the app is run. The easiest way to do this is to check
 * android:versionCode from the manifest, and compare it to a value stored
 * as a preference.
 */
private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        cameraManager.openDriver(surfaceHolder);
        // Creating the handler starts the preview, which can also throw a
        // RuntimeException.
        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats,
                    characterSet, cameraManager);
        }
        decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, null);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.w(TAG, ioe);
        displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // Barcode Scanner has seen crashes in the wild of this variety:
        // java.?lang.?RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error initializing camera", e);
        displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    }
}

private void displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_camera_framework_bug));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new FinishListener(this));
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new FinishListener(this));
    builder.show();
}

public void restartPreviewAfterDelay(long delayMS) {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview, delayMS);
    }
    resetStatusView();
}

private void resetStatusView() {
    resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    statusView.setText(R.string.msg_default_status);
    statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lastResult = null;
}

public void drawViewfinder() {
    viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();
}
/*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    shopping.txtv_no_qr_code_scan.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }*/
```

}

Comment: Try to post relevant answer... by the way, I am not the one who downvoted you.